# In node.js how to require the modules which are not in the same folder of current file

Tags: node.js, require

The below is my node.js project structure. In the folder "lib" I have "Notification.js" file, in which I want to require the "index.js" file. If that index.js file is available within the lib folder, I can use `var module=require(./index)`. But now it's not available outside of the lib folder.

```
   MyProject
      |
      |
      index.js
      lib
        |
        |
        Notification.js
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use relative imports. In your Notification.js:

```
var module = require('../index');
```

Comment: simpler: `var m = require('..');`